# Probability of getting green

Tags: probability, probability-theory

**If a bag contains *x* black balls, *y* green balls and *z* yellow balls , now a ball is drawn :**

**1. It's yellow -> try again**

**2. it's green -> stop**

**3. it's black -> stop**

***What is the probability of getting a green ball?***

I am a newbie so please forgive me if the question is too amateurish . Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the probability of getting a blue ball, as asked in the topic of this question, is not very big, since there are no blue balls in the bag.

As far as getting a green ball goes: Suppose that you've picked $m$ yellow balls before you pick a ball that's either black or green. Since there are $x+y$ green or black balls left, the chance of getting a black ball is $x/(x+y)$, and the chance of getting a green is $y/(x+y)$. In particular, the probability you are looking for is independent of $m$.

Answer (score 2):

We can simply ignore the yellow balls. They don't make any impact on the decision. So now all we have are x black balls and y green balls. Now we are to find what's the probability that in any permutation of these x+y balls the first ball is a green ball. Straight forwardly, it's **y/(x+y)**