# N Students Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

****Let there be n students each having x[i] balls in their hands. There are two boxes in front of them one by one they come and keep their balls in any one of the boxes ,each student having probability of p[i] of choosing box1 ..
Now how do we calculate the probability of box1 having more balls than box2 or same number of balls as box2 ****

*P.S: A student keeps all balls in one box, not distribute them .*

Comment: If $B_1$ and $B_2$ are the random number of balls in box 1 resp. box 2 and $x=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$, you could try
$$P(B_1>B_2) = \sum_{k=x}^{\lceil x/2\rceil } P(B_1=k).
$$

Does that help?

Comment: Can you please elaborate it a bit more ??

Comment: Now there are answers which use this idea and they are pretty detailed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me redefine $x_i = x[i]$ and $p[i] = p_i$ for cleaner notation.

Suppose $C_i$ is the box number that student $i$ chooses, but let me relabel the boxes as $1$ and $0$ (so $0$ replaces the original $2$).
$C_i$ is a Bernoulli random variable with success probability $p_i$.

The number of balls in box 1 is $A = \sum_{i=1}^n C_ix[i]$, while the number of balls in box 0 is $B = \sum_{i=1}^n (1 - C_i)x[i]$. The difference is
\begin{align}
A - B & = 
\sum_{i=1}^n \left(2C_i - 1\right)x_i \\
& = 2\sum_{i=1}^n C_i - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \\
& = 2D - x
\end{align}
where $D = \sum_{i=1}^n C_i$ and $X = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$.
So the problem reduces to computing the distribution of $D$. This is a [Poisson binomial random variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution).
The formula for the probability mass function is kind of nasty though:
$$
f(k) = P(D = k) = P\left(\sum_{i=1}^n C_i = k\right)
= \sum_{\substack{A \subseteq S\\|A| = k}}
\left(\prod_{i \in A} p_i\right)\left(\prod_{i \in S - A} (1 - p_i)\right)
$$
where $S = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$.
The sum goes through all subsets of $S$ of size $k$.

Now that we know $f$, the probability mass function of $D$, it is easy to answer all the questions asked. For example:
\begin{align}
P(A > B) & = P(A - B > 0) \\
& = P\left(2D - X > 0\right) \\
& = P\left(D > \frac 12X\right) \\
& = \sum_{k = \lceil \frac 12X \rceil}^{X} f(k).
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Let  $I_i$ indicate that student $i$ puts his/her balls in box 1.  You want  $P\{\sum x_i I_i \ge \sum x_i(1-I_i)\} = P\{\sum x_i I_i \ge \frac12 \sum x_i\}$.  To determine the distribution of $Y \equiv \sum x_i I_i$, use probability generating functions.  $\pi_{x_i I_i}(z)=\pi_{I_i}(x_i z)=1-p_i+p_i z^{x_i}$.  $\pi_Y(z)= \prod_{i=1}^N \pi_{I_i}(z)=\sum_{k=0}^M c_k z^k$, where $M=\sum x_i$.  Your desired probability is $\sum_{k \ge M/2}c_k$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your process is an example of Poisson binomial trials, but you can think of it as a random walk with n steps. This process generates a value $V$. During $i^{th}$ phase:

$V := V + x_i$ with probability $p_i$ and $V := V -x_i$ with probability $(1-p_i)$.

You are interested in $P(V $after n steps $\geq 0)$.

### But what's more important...

I'm not giving you any solution and there is a reason for that:

You should be ashamed of yourself because for the second straight time you are asking for a solution to a problem from programming competition during the contest.

Don't think that reformulation questions (flags to balls or coupons to balls) will help you to hide.

In this post you simply want a solution to [Save The Princess](http://www.codechef.com/AUG13/problems/SHIRO/) problem.

And during the last month contest, in your [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438787/probability-of-getting-green) you wanted a solution to [The Probability Of Winning](http://www.codechef.com/JULY13/problems/PROB).

Did you forget that a contest is a competition and if you can't solve a problem by yourself then you can't (a least during the coding phase)?

Comment: okay.. I just wanted to know how to tackle these questions..I didn't actually use these answers to answer the codes

Comment: From next time i will post after the contest is over ..

Comment: @SayanPaul Maybe you didn't want to use the answers to code, but since someone wrote the answer, everyone can use it.

Comment: point noted ...